# What's the difference between Dependency Property SetValue() & SetCurrentValue()

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, setvalue, setcurrentvalue

The reason why I am asking this is because I was recommended by @Greg D (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225331/is-there-something-wrong-with-my-dependency-property-content-not-set-with-bindin)) to use `SetCurrentValue()` instead, but a look at the docs and didn't see whats the difference. Or whats does "without changing its value source" mean?

[**`SetValue()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473.aspx)

> Sets the local value of a dependency property, specified by its
> dependency property identifier.

[**`SetCurrentValue()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx)

> Sets the value of a dependency property without changing its value
> source.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The MSDN link you provided says it quite well:

> This method is used by a component
>   that programmatically sets the value
>   of one of its own properties without
>   disabling an application's declared
>   use of the property. The
>   SetCurrentValue method changes the
>   effective value of the property, but
>   existing triggers, data bindings, and
>   styles will continue to work.

Suppose you're writing the `TextBox` control and you've exposed a `Text` property that people often use as follows:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
```

In your control's code, if you call `SetValue` you will *overwrite* the binding with whatever you provide. If you call `SetCurrentValue`, however, will ensure that the property takes on the given value, but won't destroy any bindings.

To the best of my knowledge, Greg's advice is incorrect. You should always use `GetValue`/`SetValue` from your CLR wrapper property. `SetCurrentValue` is more useful in scenarios where you need a property to take on a given value but don't want to overwrite any bindings, triggers, or styles that have been configured against your property.

Comment: In Vincent Sibal's blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2009/05/21/the-control-local-values-bug-solution-and-new-wpf-4-0-related-apis.aspx) you can read the following at the end. "For a control developer, the general recommendation is to always use DependencyObject.SetCurrentValue over DependencyObject.SetValue in Control code.  You’ll notice that our stock controls in the 4.0 framework have all been updated to use this API instead of setting the properties with local values." You're both probably right but can you explain the difference here and the recommendation from the blog?

Comment: @Meleak: to be honest, I think that post is a little unclear. I think he meant to say that `SetCurrentValue` should be used anywhere in your control where you want to *internally* modify a dependency property's value. Indeed, if you crack open his example project, you'll see he's still using `GetValue` and `SetValue` in the CLR property wrapper. Indeed, if you crack open reflector against .NET 4.0 you'll see that's still the case too.

Comment: Hmm, so far, I've been using `SetValue` as its generated by Visual Studio, it works fine. I don't really get what you mean by destroy the binding. After the 1st value change, my Binding don't get destroyed? cos I can still make changes and the Binding still works?

Comment: From the link @Meleak provided, I seem to be thinking, maybe `SetCurrentValue()` just sets the **Current** value and I can reset the value to the original? But whats the use of that?

Comment: @Kent: Thanks! Now I understand the difference, good answer! +1

Comment: The absence of `SetCurrentValue()` prior to .Net 4 is one thing that makes implementing a proper, self-contained, fully-featured `NumericUpDownControl` unreasonably difficult.  Clicking the classic Up/Down arrows on such a control will typically modify the value of the control programmatically, but with `SetValue()`, that blows away any bindings that the user may have implemented against that field.  `SetCurrentValue()` lets you modify the value of the property programmatically from the Up and Down buttons without destroying the binding against the backing data.

Comment: I must be the noobiest of all here... maybe can you can explain what happens when "application's use of property is disabled". How does `SetValue` cause "existing triggers, data bindings, and styles" to fail? Erm... I don't know if its too much, maybe a simple example demonstrating when I cannot just use `SetValue`? ... It seems my own question from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231478/binding-setting-property-but-ui-not-updating-can-i-debug-within-referenced-proje) only succeeds when using `SetCurrentValue` but not `SetValue`...

Comment: I tried seeing if any binding is destroyed when I use `SetValue` in this [**Screenr Video**](http://screenr.com/3Pc). and everything worked fine? Maybe I didn't do the thing that destroys the binding? But how can I do that?

Comment: I believe bindings were mainly destroyed only in cases where the Binding Mode is not TwoWay. For TwoWay bindings everything seems to work find in regard to using SetValue from my observations.

Comment: Why is it that "you will overwrite the binding" but "use GetValue/SetValue from your CLR wrapper property"?

Answer (score 4):

**demo harness (complete):**

```
class test : DependencyObject
{
    static DependencyProperty XyzProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Xyz", typeof(int), typeof(test), new PropertyMetadata(42));

    public test()
    {
        /* ... see code shown below ... */
    }

    void inf()
    {
        var info = DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource(this, XyzProperty);
        var msg = $@"{"//"
                   } {(int)GetValue(XyzProperty),2
                   } {(ReadLocalValue(XyzProperty) is int x ? "(Object)" + x : "UnsetValue"),12
                   } {info.BaseValueSource,9
                   } {(info.IsCurrent ? "" : "Not") + "Current",12
                   } {(info.IsCoerced ? "" : "Not") + "Coerced",12
                   }";
        Trace.WriteLine(msg);
    }
};
```

**discussion examples:**

```
                                      // v̲a̲l̲u̲e̲  s̲t̲o̲r̲e̲d̲-o̲b̲j̲      B̲V̲S̲    C̲u̲r̲r̲e̲n̲t̲?    C̲o̲e̲r̲c̲e̲d̲?
/*1*/                                    // 42  UnsetValue  Default  NotCurrent  NotCoerced

/*2*/ SetValue(XyzProperty, 5);          //  5   (Object)5    Local  NotCurrent  NotCoerced

/*3*/ SetValue(XyzProperty, 42);         // 42  (Object)42    Local  NotCurrent  NotCoerced

/*4*/ ClearValue(XyzProperty);           // 42  UnsetValue  Default  NotCurrent  NotCoerced

/*5*/ SetCurrentValue(XyzProperty, 5);   //  5   (Object)5  Default     Current     Coerced

/*6*/ SetCurrentValue(XyzProperty, 42);  // 42  UnsetValue  Default  NotCurrent  NotCoerced

/*7*/ SetValue(XyzProperty, 5);          //  5   (Object)5    Local  NotCurrent  NotCoerced
      SetCurrentValue(XyzProperty, 42);  // 42  (Object)42    Local     Current     Coerced
```

**discussion:**

1. Initial state of an absent `DependencyProperty` which has a `DefaultValue` of '42' has the `BaseValueSource.Default` flag asserted. `ReadLocalValue()` returns the global singleton instance `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`.
2. `SetValue()` internally stores a `BaseValueSource.Local` value as expected.
3. Using `SetValue` to store a value which happens to equal to the `DefaultValue` does not restore the `BaseValueSource.Default` state (compare to #6, below).
4. Instead, if you want to remove any/all stored value or binding and restore the DP to pristine, call `ClearValue()`. (see note below)
5. With `SetCurrentValue()`, the property value is produced via coercion, and without asserting the `BaseValueSource.Local` mode. Notice that the previous `BaseValueSource` **Default** still prevails despite the property now reporting a value which is ***not***, in fact, equal to its `DefaultValue`.

> **Important:**
> This means that checking that the `BaseValueSource` returned by `GetValueSource()` state is `BaseValueSource.Default` is ***not*** a reliable indicator of whether the prevailing property value equals the default value from the DP metatdata.

6. On the other hand--and unlike #3 above--`SetCurrentValue` ***does*** check for equality against the DP metadata's `DefaultValue`, in order to prune values it thus deems redundant as "unnecessary" as well. This eager cleanup may be designed to alleviate DP storage bloat, but it also complicates DP state transparency with a special-case "unmasking" behavior which can lead to obscure bugs if not thoroughly understood. For example, #6 clears the DP back to a pristine state indistinguishable from `ClearValue()`...
7. ***...but only*** if the previously stored `BaseValueSource` was `Current` and not `Local`; Compare #5/#6 to pair #7, where internal state flags differ considerably, despite identical reported property values.

**regarding `ClearValue()`:**

It is obvious that the `PropertyChangedCallback` is not invoked for any `SetValue()` operation that doesn't ultimately result in a change from the previous value of the property. It's fundamental because `SetValue` carries an implicit assumption that ongoing changes relate to the value of an active property at work. What's less intuitive is that the same logic applies to `ClearValue()` as well.

For example, in #4, `ClearValue` causes local value `42` to be deleted from internal DP storage, plus other internal state changes, all as expected. The problem is that whether (or not) `OnPropertyChanged` is called ***during the current `ClearValue` call*** depends on whether (or not) the previous value ***happened to equal*** the metadata default value.
Since the semantics of a "clear" operation seem to imply the summary discard of previous state--which is often therefore assumed to be contextually arbitrary--one might not expect this inconsistency where the behavior of `ClearValue()` depends on some/any previous state. Especially for a significant behavior which also implicates (and co-mingles) the **new** state, such as whether to fire "change" notification or not.

Answer (score 3):

Further to the accepted answer:

I found that [this post](http://wpf.2000things.com/2010/12/06/147-use-setcurrentvalue-when-you-want-to-set-a-dependency-property-value-from-within-a-control/) explains SetCurrentValue() quite well. Note how the Dependency Property Value Precedence system will take a local value over a bound value. Which explains the commenters unexpected behaviour.