# Debug/Breakpoint why a WPF BindingExpression is null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a WPF CustomControl with a depdendency property called SelectedRange.

In an application in XAML the binding is set like this:

```
SelectedRange="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=MainWindow},
                         Path=GlobalXRange, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

I find in the code that the BindingExpression is getting overwritten (set to null). I can determine this with this code:

```
public IRange SelectedRange
{
    get { return (IRange)GetValue(SelectedRangeProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(SelectedRangeProperty, value);
        Binding b = BindingOperations.GetBinding(this, SelectedRangeProperty);

        BindingExpression be =
             BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this, SelectedRangeProperty);
        if (be == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Binding expression is null!");
        }
    }
}
```

It turns out the BindingExpression is null after the application starts.

So my question is - how can I debug why this BindingExpression is null - e.g. it is set in XAML how can I find out where it is being set to null?

Note: There are no binding errors in the output console

Comment: Setter for `SelectedRange` will not be called if use binding. WPF will bind directly to your `SelectedRangeProperty` and call `SetValue(...)` directly on it

Comment: Ah that's true. I put the code in both SelectedRangePropertyChanged handler and the setter. It was called for both (it is being set via CLR setters and bindings). In all instances the binding expression is null (never appears to be set)

Comment: Is it always `null`? I've just created my simle `UserControl` with one `DependancyProperty` that is bound in `MainWindow` and when I check `BindingExpression` in `PropertyChangedCallback` it's never `null`

Comment: I think I've found it - I put a breakpoint in SelectedRangePropertChanged (DP callback) and I found that the SelectedRange is being set via a CLR setter before the binding is assigned. This means the binding cannot be assigned. Using DependencyObject.SetCurrentValue(SelectedRangeProperty, newValue) instead works. However ... I don't like this solution, it feels a bit too finely balanced. Also the code is cross-platform silverlight and there is no SetCurrentValue in SL

Comment: Your local value will take precedence over binding even after `Binding` is created. Why do you need to set the CLR property? Do you need to initialize it in other way then pass default value to `DependencyProperty.Register(...)`?

Comment: because I'm developing a custom control. Its very common to need to set Dependency Property values during normal running of the control. E.g. the result of a calculation or such. In WPF4 it is recommended to use SetCurrentValue over SetValue in these circumstances. I cannot for the life of me figure out why they would leave something so fundamental out of WinRT/SL

Comment: ^ There's a good example of usage of SetCurrentValue here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2009/05/21/the-control-local-values-bug-solution-and-new-wpf-4-0-related-apis.aspx 

Seems Im totally screwed, what with SL and WinRT not supporting this!

Comment: Now I know what you mean and I'm afraid that there is no obvious solution to your problem. I know the difference between `SetValue` and `SetCurrentValue` and, unfortunately, know all to well that SilverLight is constant workaround something that already exists in WPF

Comment: Its a real pain... At least from this discussion I now know why this issue is occurring, so thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

Ok guys, thanks to all your help I managed to solve this. For future readers here's how I did it.

This problem was caused by [DependencyProperty Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The TwoWay binding to SelectedRange was inside an ItemTemplate and was being overwritten by the Custom Control which was calling SetValue(SelectedRangeProperty, value).

The solution in WPF is to use [SetCurrentValue(SelectedRangeProperty, value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230698/whats-the-difference-between-dependency-property-setvalue-setcurrentvalue).

However, I am writing a cross-platform control (Silverlight, WinRT) and this method is not available in SL/WinRT. To workaround I had to create a binding to set the SelectedRangeProperty via a proxy in code, e.g.

```
var binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = this;
binding.Path = new PropertyPath(SelectedRangeProxyProperty);
binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
this.SetBinding(SelectedRangeProperty, binding);
```

Thank you for all your help, hope this helps someone else!

Comment: SetCurrentValue is the way to update control's DP indeed despite many suggestions to set two-way binding via FrameworkPropertyMetaData and then procceed with SetValue

Answer (score 2):

You can enable tracing of the binding by adding the following to the binding expression:

```
PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High
```

E.g.

```
{Binding
  Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=MainWindow},
  Path=GlobalXRange,
  Mode=TwoWay,
  PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}
```

You will then get additional information about the binding in the debug window.

Comment: That's useful. Im seeing generally the same result in the output window when the binding is updated. In the one case (using SetCurrentValue), then binding appears to be updated one way only. In the other case (SetValue) it is not updated back to the source. There are no outputs in the console window in this case as the binding expression for the property is null