# How to update one dependency property from another in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have two dependency properties and when value in *First* changes, I would like to update also the *Second* - for example give it temporary value and update UI, but I don't want to break the binding on *Second* property.

```
public bool Frist
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(FristProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FristProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty FristProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Frist", typeof(bool), typeof(ItemControl), new PropertyMetadata(false, FirstUpdated));

private static void FirstUpdated(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var theControl = d as ItemsControl;
    // I would like to update also second dependency property here
    // for example if First == true, then Second = Overriden
    // else Second = the value from binding
}

public string Second
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(SecondProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SecondProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Second", typeof(string), typeof(ItemsControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
```

I've taken a look at various samples from WPF, but seems like there are missing things in UWP. What are the options?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to find a method in UWP which is equal  to [`SetCurrentValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx) in WPF.    Since it is not available in UWP, you may vote up [this user voice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/18787915-missing-dependencyobject-setcurrentvalue) which has same requirements as you. As  a workaround you may add the broken binding again after value updated. Maybe not very good but can temporary resolve your issue.

Comment: See workaround from @Dr. ABT :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029968/debug-breakpoint-why-a-wpf-bindingexpression-is-null/20031868#20031868, adding binding code behind.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Voted. Thanks for information. Nevertheless I though there would be a differnt way than redefining binding.