# updating buttons state after refresh wpf

Tags: wpf, button, mvvm

I have 10 buttons in my UI, when I press one of them, I need to disable the rest; but here is the tricky part :

I have a background thread running under a while loop for real time update. 
the background thread update UI (the 10 buttons state and other stuff), the thing is once I click all buttons are disabled (good), but the refresh stops working on buttons (they stay disabled).

Why do I need to disable buttons knowing that they are going to change state after a second? because synchronising data  is not very efficient, there is a 0.5s gap (to get data from DB and update UI) and in that 0.5s, a user can press some buttons that he is not supposed to press.

```
<Button  Name="FirstGo" Width="60" Content="{StaticResource ButtonText_Go}" Click="FirstGoButtonClick" IsEnabled="{Binding First.JobLight,Converter={StaticResource JobLight2ButtonConv}}"/>

 private void FirstGoButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FirstStop.IsEnabled = false;

            SecondGo.IsEnabled = false;
            SecondStop.IsEnabled = false;

           //..... disabeling the other 6

           //doing some stuff  
           ViewModel.RunFirstJob();
        }
```

Comment: You are disabling all the buttons in the `FirstGoButtonClick` event but where are you enabling them all again?

Comment: I have a converter binded with a property "First.JobLight", this property gets updated by my background thread and tells the button in witch state he should be :
IsEnabled="{Binding First.JobLight,Converter={StaticResource JobLight2ButtonConv}}

the idea is, if i click a button then --> disable all buttons until the refresh happens and reset them to intial state. is it clear now ?

Comment: `First.JobLight` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the value needs to change for the converter to run. If you work out where `JobLight` changes you may find your problem

Comment: JobLight does implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and it works fine without the disabling part, meening buttons reacte perfectly to refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 FirstStop.IsEnabled = false;
```

This code removes the binding, so, the succeeding update value to JobLight won't be recognized by the framework.

What you can do is to use [SetCurrentValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230698/whats-the-difference-between-dependency-property-setvalue-setcurrentvalue).

Or put the collection of buttons into a Selector and handle the JobLight property when SelectionChanged happen.