# How to keep Two-Way Binding while updating value through Trigger/Setter in ResourceDictionary / Template Document

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

```
        <Grid x:Name="RedGrid" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisible,
        Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

As you can see the Visibility of this Grid is tied to the IsVisible property.

```
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger SourceName="RedGrid" Property="Opacity" Value="0">
                <Setter TargetName="RedGrid" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>     
            </Trigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

This part of code will change the visibility of the RedGrid once the opacity reachs / equals zero

But obviously the second part of the code doesn't work, since the Setter for IsVisible is not called when the Visibility of RedGrid is successfully changed to Collapsed.

```
    public Visibility IsVisible
    {
        get => _isVisible;

        set
        {
           _isVisible = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("IsVisible");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This `IsVisible` property, is it of type `bool` or `Visibility` ?
And can you provide a sample code of the `ViewModel` or the `DataContext`.

Comment: @AhmedZaki thanks for taking your time commenting. I added the IsVisible property to the question

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to update the `Visibility` property of the `Grid` using a `Setter` and maintain the binding at the same time. The problem is that binding is overwritten by the `Setter`!

When you use Xaml [Setters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.setter?view=net-5.0) you set properties the same way as you set them in the tag, so when you write:

```xml
<Setter TargetName="RedGrid" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
```

It acts the same way as if you've written:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="RedGrid" Visibility="Collapsed">
```

Notice that the binding `Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisible"}` has been overwritten by the value `Visibility="Collapsed"` and will no longer work.

**But Why?**

The way that `TwoWay` binding works can be found inside the controls themselves. When you work with [DependencyProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty?view=net-5.0) by default you set them using [`SetValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyobject.setvalue?view=net-5.0#remarks) method, which sets the property's value and overwrites any binding in place.

However, in controls like `TextBox` or `CheckBox` that take in user input, when the user interacts with them, properties like `TextBox.Text` and `CheckBox.IsChecked` are being set by the method [`SetCurrentValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#remarks) which like the documentation says:

> The SetCurrentValue method changes the effective value of the property, but existing triggers, data bindings, and styles will continue to work.

You can review this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230698/whats-the-difference-between-dependency-property-setvalue-setcurrentvalue) for more information about the differences between `SetValue()` and `SetCurrentVaule()` methods.

**What to do:**

In your case, I think that you can add a `GridOpacity` property to the view model, and instead of changing the `Visibility` in Xaml using a `Setter`, you can change the view model's `IsVisible` property directly when you set the `GridOpacity` property.

Here is a sample code of the view model:

```
private Visibility _isVisible;
public Visibility IsVisible
{
    get => _isVisible;
    set
    {
        if (_isVisible == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        _isVisible = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsVisible));
    }
}

private double _gridOpacity;
public double GridOpacity
{
    get => _gridOpacity;
    set
    {
        if (_gridOpacity == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        _gridOpacity = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(GridOpacity));

        // Change the visibility of the grid when opacity hits 0.
        if (value == 0)
        {
            IsVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            // Change it back.
            IsVisible = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="RedGrid" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}" Opacity="{Binding GridOpacity}">
    ...
</Grid>
```